# How to print the name of a value from a split string in java?

Tags: java, split

I'm supposed to write a program that asks for people's name and age and then prints the oldest person's name. (Sorry some parts of the programming are not in english, but I hope someone understands enough to help). It's an assignment and I have to do it by splitting the string.

The print should be like this:

James,2
Mary,2
Jessica,1
Jennifer,5
Gabriel,10

The name of the oldest: Gabriel

I know how to print the highest age, but not the name of it. This is how i've done it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    int oldest = -1;
    while (true) {
        String mjono = lukija.nextLine();
        if (mjono.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
        String[] pieces = mjono.split(",");
        int age = Integer.valueOf(pieces[1]);
        if (age > oldest) {
            oldest = age;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The oldest age: " + oldest);
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the input of:

```
James,2
Mary,2
Jessica,1
Jennifer,5
Gabriel,10
```

We can read line by line and then get the oldest person by the following class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class OldestPerson {
    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        PriorityQueue<Person> queue = new PriorityQueue<Person>((a, b) -> b.getAge() - a.getAge());
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tmp = line.split(",");
            queue.add(new Person(tmp[0], Integer.parseInt(tmp[1])));
        }
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Person oldestPerson = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(oldestPerson.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to do that is simply comparing the person age directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    String oldestPerson = "";
    int age = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tmp = line.split(",");
        if (age < Integer.parseInt(tmp[1])) {
            age = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
            oldestPerson = tmp[0];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(oldestPerson);
}
```